# Joining one table with 3 others

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

Could someone help me with joining these tables together?

http://i.imgur.com/kbOEGnx.png?1

After i joined them like this:

```
SELECT TableA.*, TableB.*, TableC.*, TableD.*
FROM TableA
    JOIN TableB
        ON TableB.aID = TableA.aID
    JOIN TableC
        ON TableC.cID = TableB.cID
    JOIN TableD
        ON TableD.dID = TableA.dID
```

It did not give me all rows from issue-tickets table. How can i join these tables to be able to get all info from issue_tickets, but equipment name instead of equipment_id? The same thing i want to do with issue_categories and issue_status.

Hoping for help!
Thanks!

Comment: There is no issue-tickets table in your query. But ant basic guide to JOINs would answer you question.

Comment: Please provide more information, some sample data, the results you are getting, and the result you desire to receive.

Comment: where is issue-tickets ??

Comment: When i try : "SELECT issue_tickets.id, issue_tickets.date_created, issue_tickets.date_due, issue_tickets.summary, issue_tickets.description, issue_tickets.solution, equipment.name, issue_status.status, issue_categories.name ....and join like i posted" it shows me only 2 rows, but when i write: SELECT * from issue_tickets it gives me 5 rows (but the three last issue_tickets elements have  values of tinyint,smallint and smallint). How should i get all elements fom issue_tickets with the name of equipment, issue_status and issue_categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **LEFT JOIN** instead of **JOIN** it will fetch all the records from LEFT table and matched data from RIGHT table

Try this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.date_created, t.date_due, t.summary, t.description, t.solution, 
       e.name, s.status, c.name
FROM issue_tickets t
LEFT JOIN equipment e on t.equipment_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN issue_status s on t.issue_status_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN issue_categories c on t.issue_categories_id = c.id
```